# problem with email parsing with python and multiple Received records

Tags: python, parsing, email

I am trying to parse emails with python email.parser. When my email contains multiple Received records, email.parser seems like ignoring those records.

Fore example, for input :

```
...
Received: from localhost (jalapeno [127.0.0.1])
    by jmason.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5C4E816F6D
    for <jm@localhost>; Sun,  6 Oct 2002 22:54:39 +0100 (IST)
Received: from jalapeno [127.0.0.1]
    by localhost with IMAP (fetchmail-5.9.0)
    for jm@localhost (single-drop); Sun, 06 Oct 2002 22:54:39 +0100 (IST)
...
```

the output is :

```
...
Received ::: from localhost (jalapeno [127.0.0.1])
    by jmason.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5C4E816F6D
    for <jm@localhost>; Sun,  6 Oct 2002 22:54:39 +0100 (IST)
Received ::: from localhost (jalapeno [127.0.0.1])
    by jmason.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5C4E816F6D
    for <jm@localhost>; Sun,  6 Oct 2002 22:54:39 +0100 (IST)
...
```

I am using the following python code

```
import email
f = open('email.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
e = email.message_from_string(data)
for i in e.keys():
    print i, ':::', e[i]
```

Is this a bug of email.parser?

Do you suggest any other email parsing python library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html) for `email.__getitem__()` says:

> Note that if the named field appears
>   more than once in the message’s
>   headers, exactly which of those field
>   values will be returned is undefined.
>   Use the get_all() method to get the
>   values of all the extant named
>   headers.

so, use e.get_all(i) instead of e[i] to get all values of the Received: header.