# Brainstorming: parsing txt emails into a structured object (JSON etc)

Tags: python, json, email

for my thesis project I will be handling a shitload of emails.
I need to extract all the header fields and pipe them into a data structure of sorts, preferably something somewhat universal like JSON.

Now, I have been looking into this and found a lot of half-ass working solutions.
I don't want you to tell me how to do this, just throw some ideas on the table.

Right now my plan is to use python to parse the header fields.
I chose python because it's nice and easy and I have had experience with it. Furthermore, lots of libraries.
Problem is python official email handling does not work well with repeated fields and that is critical to me. Especially for the header "Received:" since this one allows to track the email travel across multiple mail servers.

The official library ignores multiple fields and just stores the first one -.-"

Any ideas? How would you tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be helpful to you: [problem with email parsing with python and multiple Received records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161122/problem-with-email-parsing-with-python-and-multiple-received-records)

> The python doc for email.**getitem**() says:
>
> Note that if the named field appears more than once in the message’s
>   headers, exactly which of those field values will be returned is
>   undefined. Use the get_all() method to get the values of all the
>   extant named headers.
>
> so, use e.get_all(i) instead of e[i] to get all values of the
>   Received: header.